# C++ Error on import CV2 , Tensorflow Ubuntu AMI version 4

Tags: python, tensorflow, amazon-ec2, anaconda

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "./src/train.py", line 9, in 
    import cv2

ImportError: /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p27/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/../../././libicui18n.so.58)

Environment : Source activate tensorflow_p27 ( p3.2xLarge instance )

---

Hi,

I am trying to run the function train.py which gives me an error on "import CV2".

I did not update the code, or environment or system to avoid any conflicts.

Additionally, I already tried to do a "sudo apt-get upgrade" and the issue still persists.

I performed "conda update --all" and tried again, to no avail.

I am unable to train my models as the system errors at this statement in the command.

The same scripts are working on a P2.xlarge instance without any errors.

I tried StackOverFlow and google search to no avail.
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The conflict happens due to version conflict between the Ubuntu system version, anaconda version and tensorflow_p27 environment version of the libstdc++.so.6 files.

The simplest way to diagnose is

```
strings /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p27/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep CXXABI
```

This should show you the versions of CXXABI available in the TF environment.

Similarly run

```
strings /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep CXXABI
```

and you should see the versions, in this case 1.3.8 available.

The final solution comes from

```
ln -svf <path-to-system-libstdc++.so.6> <dest-path-to-env-libstdc++.so.6>
```

This solution worked for me for other lib-XYZABC (e.g. libgomp GOMP-4.0) errors as well. Packaging by anaconda into the environment, independent of tensorflow picking some versions of libraries, is likely the root cause of the problem.

Hope it helps

Thanks